# ¿Cómo diferenciar 2 ID sacados de una misma tabla? php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

disculpen por no hacer clara la pregunta
paso a explicarles mejor,
la cosa es que yo tengo una tabla *equipos* que contiene los nombres de los mismos con sus respectivos ID, el tema es si yo tengo una *tabla partido* que se compone de 2 IDequipos como hago yo para que en esta tabla el idequipo1 sea **si o si diferente** al idequipo2

> NOTA: El *idequipo_local* y *idequipo_visitante* tiene que aparecer SOLO una vez para una misma fecha, osea el idequipo=4 solo juega una y solo una vez en una fecha determinada, así como también ese idequipo no puede aparecer en las 2 columnas, es decir *idequipo_local* siempre tiene que ser distinto a *idequipo_visitante* (osea un equipo no puede enfrentarse a si mismo)
>
> ADJUNTO TABLAS:
>   [image: tabla partido][image: tabla equipos]

Me surge la duda si todo esto es posible controlarlo en MYSQL o solamente se controla validando con php?? mi idea seria validar de ambos lados

saludos , espero que me entiendan

Comment: quieres que el id sea diferente en php?

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez nono en la base de datos, es posible restringirlo?? o si o si lo tengo que hacer del lado de php??

Comment: Agrega las tablas (estructura) y ejemplo de como serian esos 2 equipos que quierres diferenciar; esta por demás decir que su diferencia debiera ser un numero de serie, control de inventario o ID (autoincremento)... amplia la info.

Comment: entonces tienes una tabla con equipos, luego tienes otra tabla donde tienes partidos (local) vs (visitante), ahora bien, ¿quieres que en la tabla partidos el id de un equipo sea distinto cuando juega como local de cuando juega como visitante?

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez nono lo que yo quiero es que no permita que se ingrese el mismo Idequipo en los campos local y visitante para un mismo partido no se si me explico?? ahi adjunto las tablas

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas ahi agrege las tablas y explico un poco mejor lo que quiero, espero que me entiendas, saludos

Answer (score 2):

Para controlarlo desde mysql, necesitas un Trigger algo asi:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PlayingWithMyself BEFORE INSERT ON partidos
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.equipo1 = NEW.equipo2 THEN
           BEGIN
             rollback transaction
             raiserror ('Prohibido jugar conmigo mismo', 16, 1)
           END
    END
```

no lo he probado pero debería ser algo así, para lo de las fechas:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PlayingOnce BEFORE INSERT ON partidos
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF (SELECT count(*) FROM partidos  
           where (NEW.equipo1=partidos.equipo1 
           or NEW.equipo2=partidos.equipo1
           or NEW.equipo1=partidos.equipo2 
           or NEW.equipo2=partidos.equipo2) and NEW.fecha=partidos.fecha)>0 
        THEN
           BEGIN
             rollback transaction
             raiserror ('Prohibido jugar conmigo mismo', 16, 1)
           END
    END
```

Comment: Amigo me da error de sintaxis en la linea 10, que puede ser??